# React detect device when the page's width or height changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to have a global variable which tells me what device I am currently using, my team wants me to have mobile, tablet, desktop and mobile landscape.
I didn't have any idea how to do that, but I started digging in google and found out this function:

```
const DeviceDetector = () => {
    
      let hasTouchScreen = false;
      if ("maxTouchPoints" in navigator) {
        hasTouchScreen = navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0;
      } else if ("msMaxTouchPoints" in navigator) {
        hasTouchScreen = navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0;
      } else {
        const mQ = matchMedia("(pointer:coarse)");
        if (mQ && mQ.media === "(pointer:coarse)") {
          hasTouchScreen = !!mQ.matches;
        } else if ("orientation" in window) {
          hasTouchScreen = true; // deprecated, but good fallback
        } else {
          // Only as a last resort, fall back to user agent sniffing
          const UA = navigator.userAgent;
          hasTouchScreen =
            /\b(BlackBerry|webOS|iPhone|IEMobile)\b/i.test(UA) ||
            /\b(Android|Windows Phone|iPad|iPod)\b/i.test(UA);
        }
      }
      if (hasTouchScreen) {
        setDeviceType("Mobile");
      } else {
        setDeviceType("Desktop");
      }
    }
```

but the problems here are two, first: this function only detects mobile and desktop, but the bigger problem is: I need this function to fire whenever the width or height of the page changes, which I tried doing by adding it in this useEffect:

```
useEffect(() =>{
      DeviceDetector();

      console.log('changing device type', deviceType);
      
    },[window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, window.outerWidth, window.outerHeight])
```

For a moment it seemed its working fine, but when its firing its showing either always mobile or desktop depends on what you loaded the page with.
I would be glad if some of you encountered the same problem and can face me in the right direction, is there a tool to make things easier, I read of react-device-detect but it seems that it also needs a page refresh to detect device changes.
I tried a bunch of things regarding the landscape mobile but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hook. Previously I have been using this to access the screen dimensions:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function getWindowDimensions() {
  const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
  return {
    width,
    height
  };
}

export default function useWindowDimensions() {
  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(getWindowDimensions());

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowDimensions;
}
```

You can map the dimensions to devices to get what you're looking for.

Comment: I just tested your hook, but again it seems to be working like react-detect-device, its loading only the width and height you firstly loaded the page with, after than it doesn't change until you don't refresh again. I need something that changes the state everytime the width and height of the page are changed

Comment: Are you sure? When I'm using this hook it changes the dimension state when I'm resizing the viewport (using Chrome)

Comment: Maybe I am not using the hook properly, I tried importing it and assigning it to a state, like that: const [deviceType, setDeviceType] = useState(useWindowDimensions()); and then tried useEffect to log the deviceType everytime the deviceType changes, but the logs were identical a.k.a its not changing, maybe its my bad, how exactly did you use the hook ?

Comment: I'm using it here: https://github.com/danielsteman/spotifycluster/blob/master/react-frontend/src/components/Plot.js, so make sure that Plot component is always fullscreen.

Comment: hmm, starnge, changing it from const [deviceType, setDeviceType] = useState(useWindowDimensions()) to  - const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions() seem to be solving the problem, thank you a lot!